# how to route angular to new page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular application where I wnat to route the user to a new page after succesfull login. But the webpage is not loading just the url is changing, I tried router-outlet but it renders the component under my login component. What I want  is to route to a complete new page.

App-routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard' , component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'authenticate', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '' , redirectTo: 'authenticate', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

App component.html

```
  <nb-layout-header fixed >
    Moniesta
  </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-layout-column>
    <moniesta-login></moniesta-login>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </nb-layout-column>

  <nb-layout-footer fixed>
    <!-- Insert footer here -->
  </nb-layout-footer>

</nb-layout>
```

Method in my service to load to new url and webpage:

```
  authenticateUser(login: LoginModel){
    return this.http.post(environment.rootUrl + 'authenticate', {
      username: login.username,
      password: login.password,
    }).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
       localStorage.setItem('token', data.toString())
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
      }, error: (error) => {
        this.isAuthenticated = false
      }
    })
  }
```

Could someone help me out and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Check the webbrowser console (F12). Do you see any errors?

Comment: no there are no errors, it just renders my component under the login component if i use router-outlet

Comment: does no one have an idea on how to do the routing?

Comment: i think there is a problem with localStorage setItem
`localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: but the change in url happens? And routeroutlet does render my component under the login component. It just does not show it as a new webpage

Comment: I still tried it is not working, the behavior stays the samer

Comment: I also tried to change it navigateByUrl but it did not change anything...

Comment: You might want to read up a bit more on routing in Angular (hint: you’ll need a router-outlet). There are no real ‘pages’ here as Angular is a SPA.

Comment: I tried to use it but it only renders the component under the currently rendered component. How can i make it render as a new page? Every example I read in the internet does it like I am doing

Comment: Your login component should also be routed and will then also load in your router-outlet. In other words, your login component shouldn’t be in app-component next to your router-outlet.

Comment: Yes this was my mistake thank you :)